# Cannot delete resource from android with resty lib

Tags: java, rest, resty

I am using [Resty](https://github.com/beders/Resty/) 0.3.2 on android
I have used all the methods successful but i cannot use delete bequese of the folowing error

in the beging I thought that was permission on manifest but all the other methods( post, put get ) are working fine.

code for delete

```
request.json("http://example.com:port/customer/4", delete());
```

the out put from logcat :

```
02-26 00:10:56.736: W/System.err(1116): java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed
02-26 00:10:56.747: W/System.err(1116): at java.io.BufferedInputStream.streamClosed(BufferedInputStream.java:118)
02-26 00:10:56.747: W/System.err(1116): at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:279)
02-26 00:10:56.747: W/System.err(1116): at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
02-26 00:10:56.747: W/System.err(1116): at us.monoid.web.AbstractResource.fill(AbstractResource.java:44)
02-26 00:10:56.757: W/System.err(1116): at us.monoid.web.Resty.fillResourceFromURL(Resty.java:432)
02-26 00:10:56.757: W/System.err(1116): at us.monoid.web.Resty.doPOSTOrPUT(Resty.java:394)
02-26 00:10:56.757: W/System.err(1116): at us.monoid.web.Resty.json(Resty.java:223)
02-26 00:10:56.757: W/System.err(1116): at us.monoid.web.Resty.json(Resty.java:228)
02-26 00:10:56.757: W/System.err(1116): at com.example.resttest.RestTasks.doRequest(RestTasks.java:57)
02-26 00:10:56.757: W/System.err(1116): at com.example.resttest.RestTasks.doInBackground(RestTasks.java:29)
02-26 00:10:56.757: W/System.err(1116): at com.example.resttest.RestTasks.doInBackground(RestTasks.java:1)
02-26 00:10:56.767: W/System.err(1116): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)

02-26 00:10:56.767: W/System.err(1116): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-26 00:10:56.767: W/System.err(1116): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-26 00:10:56.777: W/System.err(1116): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-26 00:10:56.777: W/System.err(1116): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-26 00:10:56.793: W/System.err(1116): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: It looks like resty is having trouble reading the response. Are you sure that the server is responding as expected?

Comment: Yes the server is responding as expected I test it with the Poster plug-in in Firefox.